# How to unit test my class without any unit test framework - visual studio setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have a c++ project in Visual Studio. It has 1 class and now I want to unit test that class. For that I have created another console application project in the same solution, and in that project created an object, called a method and asserted what it returns.

The only problem I am having is that linker complains as it does not have object files or .lib file from the original project that I am testing. How to export a lib and link it in test project? Or is there a better way to say test project to compile .cpp files for himself?

Please advice.

Comment: Why are you refraining from test frameworks? Google test is pretty nifty. Also IIRC Visual Studio comes with it's own.

Comment: Adde the actual source files from the other project in the "test" project. Not physically, like copying from disk, just drag and copy in the workspace source tree.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this is a solution but not literate I think?? :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the problem here is not the framework. As even with Visual Studio Testing framework you should export a .dll from one project and import to other one.

Comment: @Narek It doesn't need to export a DLL, but you should organize your code going under test as a separate library (can be static as well). That's anyway the better way to organize your code. Executables should be very thin wrappers for your application.

Answer (score 1):

The unit tests should be compiled or linked with the application under test.

If you plan to separate out your unit tests visual studio project with main application visual studio project, you can create a static or dynamic link library of main studio studio project and link this with unit test project.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953.aspx this says to create a .dll, can I say my original project to work as it was, with its `main` function but also export a dll?

Comment: Yeah you can export your classes/methods into dll. I would prefer a static library though, unless your application creates a dll only. With unit tests your entry point i.e main function should be re-written to actually call your unit tests instead of normal call flow.

Answer (score 1):

> How to export a lib and link it in test project? Or is there a better way to say test project to compile .cpp files for himself?

The question isn't so much about using a unit testing framework or not, but what's the best way to organize your application code in your solution.

The stuff that should go under test should be a separate static or shared library project, that can be linked with different executables.

Your regular application should be a thin delegate from the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` executable entry point, like:

```
 class Application {
 public:
       Application(int argc, char* argv[]);
       int run();
 };
```

So you can easily provide a unit test for this class as well.

---

Most testing frameworks already provide an appropriate implementation of the `main()` function to run all the test cases, or you provide your own console application and use `assert()`.

---

BTW, that's not a problem restricted to visual studio, but it will be faced with any IDE or build system.